# Sending string from one C++ program to another and waiting for a response

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

We will be running two C++ win32 console programs simultaneously in visual studio 2010. We want to be able to send a message(string) from one to another. Program 1 sends a message to program 2 and waits for program 2 to send a message back. Once program 2 sends a reply, it now waits for the next message from program 1 without quitting.

Comment: Are both apps running? or can app #1 start app #2?

Comment: Look into using sockets? If both programs are always on the same computer though, you could use shared memory.

Comment: Read more on [IPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication)

Comment: updated the question for more clarity.

Comment: Which part of the task is unclear ? 
1) How to send a message from one process to another ? If this is the case, i.e. you are running programs in the same machine. 
2) How to implement the protocol itself ? 
Sound like you want to write a messenger :)

Comment: @artapet we are looking for the best way to send messages between programs and make them wait for each other.

Comment: @user1319424: "the best way" is subjective. There are many different ways to accomplish that, each with its own advantages and disadvantages. You need to evaluate each one and decide for yourself which approach best suits your actual needs. One approach that is suitable for one type of situation may not be the best choice for another situation.

Comment: What you have said there is more like a problem statement rather than a question. What is your question?

Comment: @yasouser how do i send "Hello" from one program to another and wait for a reply. In C++

Comment: Shared Memory mapping is one possible way for your requirement. You can create and map a structure into a global memory segment, available to every applications in the OS, diffentiate by a object name. But the final synchronization of the data passing has to be designed and coded by you. Refer to this link for a wrapper class:  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1362/A-Simple-Wrapper-for-Sharing-Data-Structures-Betwe

Answer (score 2):

There are many different ways to exchange data between multiple apps running on the same PC.  They fall under the general blanket term "Inter Process Communication".  Use whatever IPC mechanism you are most comfortable with - Files, Registry, Sockets, Named Pipes, MailSlots, ActiveX, Remote Procedure Calls, Shared Memory, or the WM_COPYDATA window message.  They all have their advantages and disadvantages, so you need to decide for yourself which one best suits your actual needs.

Comment: Thanks. We looked at `WM_COPYDATA` and understood it to a certain extent. Can you explain how the `SendMessage(..)` and `GetMessage` work? How do i send a string? I am able to connect and find the correct window using `FindWindow`

Comment: `COPYDATASTRUCT cds; cds.dwData = AUniqueId; cds.lpData = "my string"; cds.cbData = strlen((char*)cds.lpData); SendMessage(hOtherAppWnd, WM_COPYDATA, (WPARAM)hThisAppWnd, (LPARAM)&cds);`

Comment: can you please clarify the usage of `hThisAppWnd` in `SendMessage`. How should the other program be receiving this? We are using `GetMessage` as shown:
`MSG msg;
 while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
 {
  std::cout << "got message" << &msg<<std::endl;
 }`

Comment: `LRESULT WINAPI wndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
  if (uMsg == WM_COPYDATA)
  {
    COPYDATASTRUCT *cds = (COPYDATASTRUCT*)lParam;
    if (cds->dwData == AUniqueId)
    {
      // use cds->lpData up to cds->cbData bytes as needed ...;

      return SomeResult;
      /*or:
      ReplyMessage(SomeResult);
      SendMessage((HWND)wParam, ...);
      return 0;*/
    }
  }
  return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, LParam);
}`

Comment: `GetMessage()` receives messages that are posted via `PostMessage()`, not messages sent via `SendMessage()`. `WM_COPYDATA` requires `SendMessage()`. Your receiving app needs to use `RegisterClass()` or `SetWindowLong/Ptr()` to associate a window procedure callback with its receiving `HWND` so it can receive sent messages. If the receiving app needs to send a message back, the sending app passes its own `HWND` in the `wParam` of `WM_COPYDATA` so the receiving app knows where to send to, in which case the sending app needs a window procedure callback of its own.

Comment: If we were to use `PostMessage`, how would we implement the same thing - send a string "hello"

Comment: You cannot use `PostMessage()` to pass a string (or anything else that does not fit fully inside of a `WPARAM`/`LPARAM`) across process boundaries. The string will not be serialized from the sender's address space to the receiver's address space. Only a few select messages do the necessary serialization, and `WM_COPYDATA` is one of them (`WM_GETTEXT` is another, for example). You have to use `SendMessage()` so it can ensure the buffers specified in the message remain valid in memory until the message is finished being processed on the other end.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24218/discussion-between-user1319424-and-remy-lebeau)

Comment: We're assuming `wndProc` is a handler, which is being overridden... is it called any time the receiving program gets a message? Is that how it works or something else needs to be done to trigger it? Just trying to get a handle of this whole concept...

Answer (score 0):

See here for example and explanation on a simple program to send data between server and client using sockets: [Getting Started with Winsock (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

This is one of the methods to do inter-process communication. For other inter-process communication methods in windows see here: [Interprocess Communications (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)